# Logstash not creating indexes in Windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have used the zip files to start logstash, kibana and elasticsearch. I am ingesting a csv file from logstash to elastic search

```
           input {
            file {
                path => "D:\tls202_part01\tls202_part01.csv"
                start_position => "beginning"
            }
        }
        filter {
            csv {
                separator => ","
                columns => ["appln_id", "appln_title_lg", "appln_title"]
            }
            mutate {
                convert => ["appln_id", "integer"]
                convert => ["appln_title_lg", "string"]
                convert => ["appln_title", "string"]
            }
        }
        output {
            elasticsearch {
                hosts => "localhost"
                index => "title"
            }
            stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
            }
        }
```

this is my config file. When I search for index title it is not there and logstash logs are these:

```
   Sending Logstash logs to D:/logstash-6.5.4/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-12-26T10:22:35,672][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-12-26T10:22:35,699][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.5.4"}
[2018-12-26T10:22:41,588][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-12-26T10:22:42,051][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-12-26T10:22:42,297][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-12-26T10:22:42,370][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-12-26T10:22:42,376][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-12-26T10:22:42,417][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost"]}
[2018-12-26T10:22:42,439][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-12-26T10:22:42,473][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-12-26T10:22:43,330][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"D:/logstash-6.5.4/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_bb5ff7ebd070422c5b611ac87e9e7087", :path=>["D:\\tls202_part01\\tls202_part01.csv"]}
[2018-12-26T10:22:43,390][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x389cc614 run>"}
[2018-12-26T10:22:43,499][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2018-12-26T10:22:43,532][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2018-12-26T10:22:43,842][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

The CSV file is large of 2GB csv data.
Also, kibana is showing no Elasticsearch data found for creating indexes.

Comment: Try commenting small subsections of your logstash config file and see if the code works(Mainly Filter).Also you could add sincedb_path => "NUL"  to your file in input in the same config file.

Comment: not working sincedb is already defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that logstash didn't found your file, change your path from backslash to forward slash and see if it works.

```
path => "D:/tls202_part01/tls202_part01.csv"
```

Comment: it is working by changing from back slash to front slash.

Comment: My god, you save my life, struggle 3 days and the solution is so weird.